# Crystal Reports: This function cannot be used because it must be evaluated later

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am currently trying to report on **stock quantities** with a timeframe for each item in stock;

- Stock at the selected minimum date within the timeframe
- Stock at the selected max date within the timeframe

I have a single quantity field of an item from a transaction which I am adding to my report twice however both with differing formulas under select expert.

- `Stocks.Date = MINIMUM(Stocks.Date)`
- `Stocks.Date = MAXIMUM(Stocks.Date)`

I've grouped by product and have all fields in the group header. I have tried looking online for solutions but I haven't found anything that really solves the problem. If you need more information please ask, this is wrecking my brain.

[image]

Essentially what I want is(for each stock item):

- **Quantity field1:**
  `SELECT Stock.Quantity WHERE Stock.Date = MINUMUM(Stock.Date)`
- **Quantity field2:**
  `SELECT Stock.Quantity WHERE Stock.Date = MAXIMUM(Stock.Date)`

Hope this helps clarify what I'm after

Comment: Give more details about the problem. which lang? If possible share the screenshot.

Comment: I'm making the report in C# and the report formulae is Crystal Syntax

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/dwykn83rp/Capture.png

Comment: what is the exact select expert code. can you post?

Comment: can you post the image in your question itselt.. I can't open your link

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post a picture in the question unfortunately, sorry! Stocks.Date = MINIMUM(Stocks.Date) and the other being  Stocks.Date = MAXIMUM(Stocks.Date). These are applied to quantity fields of a product

Comment: I have posted the image

Answer (score 1):

You can't include Crystal's aggregate functions in the record selection formula because it is self-referential. It's like saying "define set A as the largest element of set A". In your case, you're effectively saying, "Only include records in my report where the date is the most recent record in my report"... doesn't make sense.

Instead, you have to include all records and only "process" the ones where `{StockSales.Date}=maximum({StockSales.Date},{StockSales.ItemID})`. You can accomplish this by comparing the date of each record to the maximum date for that item ID and saving the stock quantity off in a variable if it is a match. You can then display the variable in the item's group footer.

The first step is to move all your Group Header 1 elements into Group Footer 1 instead. Then you'll need to create 2 new formulas to manage the variable:

```
//{@Update variable}
// Place this formula in the Details section
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar qty;
if {StockSales.Date}=maximum({StockSales.Date},{StockSales.ItemID})
 then qty := {StockSales.Quantity}

//{Display variable}
// Place this formula in the Group Footer 1 section where you want the quantity to display
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar qty;
```

Comment: You can reference a SQL expression that calculates an aggregate in the record-selection formula.

Comment: @craig Right, I'll edit to make it clearer which aggregate functions I'm referring to.

Comment: I won't be able to test this right away but I try as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

Create two SQL expression fields:

```
// {%MIN_DATE}
(
  SELECT MINIMUM(Date) FROM Stock
)

// {%MAX_DATE}
(
  SELECT MAXIMUM(Date) FROM Stock
)
```

Then reference them in the record-selection formula:

```
{Stock.Date} IN [{%MIN_DATE},{%MAX_DATE}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Select Expert` doesn't make any sense to me.

You are retriving the records from `Min Date` to `Max Date` in other words you are retriving the whole table data in to your report in this case what is the use of select expert.

If you don't mention any thing in select expert then also you can whole table data.

If you really want to filter some data then provide some paramters to the user so that you can filter in those parameters then your select expert will become something like.

```
Stocks.Date>={?StartDate} and Stocks.Date<={?EndDate}
```

If my understanding is wrong then edit the question clearly with your requirement.

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

In this case don't use select expert, Do calculations in your report itself in formula fields.

create a formula as:

```
@Minimumn

if Stock.Date = MINUMUM(Stock.Date)
then <Stockitemahere>
```

For Maximum create another formula as:

```
@Maximum

if Stock.Date = MAXIMUM(Stock.Date)
then <Stockitemahere>
```

Place both formulas on design part of the report.

Take care date filtering shouldn't be in select expert

Comment: I'm looking only for two single dates for a product, not all dates in between. I was hoping for the formulae in the picture to retrieve the earliest date recorded/Mininum Date for a product of a transaction. I get the same problem for when I try the most recent/Maximum Date for a product of a transaction.

Comment: No errors are coming up but the report doesn't seem to be giving any results, I'll just double check to make sure I haven't made any mistakes myself. Will mark this as the answer when I see the results come through :)

Comment: No problem check and let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: Unfortunately not quite what I'm after, it'll search against existing values being reported but not substitute in the min/max values for that item but if an item just so happens to report a min/max date then it will return a quantity. I may need to look into an alternate solution/different way to go about the report.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to show the max and min in the report, then you can try the below Steps:

Go to the Group field, Right Click on the object ->`Format Object`->`Display String`-> Give the Formula:

```
CStr (Maximum ({Stocks.Date}));
```

To show both min and max in the same report, drag the Date field twice into the report and for one object give Minimum Date another with Max date.

For Maximum:    `CStr (Maximum ({Stocks.Date}));`
For Minimum :    `CStr (Minimum ({Stocks.Date}));`

Comment: Sorry if I've mislead, I need to display the quantities of a stock item and not the date. The date won't be shown at all in the final report

Comment: In place of Date use the quantity field.